# Best approach to doing automatic analysis of sets of tags in Excel/Access/or similar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access, tags

I have a large set of open-ended responses to a survey (~10,000), and each has been assigned a set of tags representing what the person has said in the response. This data is sitting in an Excel spreadsheet.

I'd like to be able to search, sort, and do analysis on the responses to the survey using combinations of tags.

For instance, to look for complaints about customer service, I'd look for rows containing the tag 'customer service' in one column and the tag 'complaint' in another.

While it's relatively simple in Excel to search for something like that on a one-off case, what's really needed is a way to see something like a pivot table that shows the most frequent combinations of tags and allows for drilling down to see what additional tags are most commonly found alongside that combination of tags.

I've done some looking around into using something like Access, and I've seen some similar-seeming functionality achieved through custom Excel wizardry. But I'm not familiar enough with Access or advanced enough with Excel to decide in advance whether either would be suitable for the task with a reasonable expenditure of effort.

Is there a solution that will easily allow this kind of analysis with a tagging approach?

Comment: This is best done with Access.  You can create a form to select different tag combinations.  The results can be populated below in a table like spreadsheet.